# Load other template or redirect

Tags: php, templates, http-redirect

In my `home` controller I'm checking whether the user is logged in or not. See the code below:

```
<?php
class Home extends Controller {
    private $db;
    private $session;

    public function __construct($db, $session) {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->session = $session;
        parent::__construct($db, $session);
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->view('home/index', array('user' => $x ) );
    }

    public function login() {
        if( $this->session->loggedIn == true ) {
            $this->index();
            exit();
        }

        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
            $sessionToDb = $this->session->startSession( $_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_password'] );
            if( $sessionToDb  === true ) {
                $this->index();
                exit();
            }
            else {
                $data['error'] = '<p>Fout tijdens inloggen.<br />'.$x.'</p>';
            }
        }
        $data['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $this->view('home/login', $data);
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->session->endSession();
        $this->login();
        exit();
    }

}
?>
```

If the user is already logged in, he should be able to see the login screen, so I added this code:

```
public function login() {
    if( $this->session->loggedIn == true ) {
        $this->index();
        exit();
    }
```

Which works... however the URL stays the same: `admin/home/login/`, which could be confusing.

So alternatively I could redirect the user:

```
public function login() {
    if( $this->session->loggedIn == true ) {
        header('Location: /admin/home/index/';
        exit();
    }
```

Same goes for the `logout()`function.

Which is the better approach?

Comment: try render or redirect $this->render('index');
any MVC framework?

Comment: to me use the header('location ..') is a good approach, and actually i don't know how to do it by an other way

Comment: look like redirect better approach

Comment: This seems like a good example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php